# OnGlobalLayoutListener in Mono for Android

Tags: c#, java, android, xamarin.android

Can anybody explain me this Java code in C#, since I use Mono for Android? For example I can't find OnGlobalLayoutListener in Mono for Android.

On Android it looks like this:

```
vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    int newWidth, newHeight, oldHeight, oldWidth;

    //the new width will fit the screen
    newWidth = metrics.widthPixels;

    //so we can scale proportionally
    oldHeight = iv.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
    oldWidth = iv.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
    newHeight = Math.floor((oldHeight * newWidth) / oldWidth);
    iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(newWidth, newHeight));
    iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

    //so this only happens once
    iv.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
    }
});
```

What is the Mono for Android equivalent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`OnGlobalLayoutListener` is an interface, so in C# it is exposed as [`ViewTreeObserver.IOnGlobalLayoutListener`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.Views.ViewTreeObserver.IOnGlobalLayoutListener). Since C# doesn't support anonymous classes as seen here in Java, you would need to provide an implementation of that interface and pass that into [`AddOnGlobalLayoutListener()`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M:Android.Views.ViewTreeObserver.AddOnGlobalLayoutListener):

```
public class MyLayoutListener : Java.Lang.Object, ViewTreeObserver.IOnGlobalLayoutListener
{
    public void OnGlobalLayout()
    {
        // do stuff here
    }
}

vto.AddOnGlobalLayoutListener(new MyLayoutListener());
```

You can do this if you want, but the preferred way in Mono for Android is to use events in place of listener interfaces. In this case, it is exposed as the [`GlobalLayout`](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=E:Android.Views.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout) event:

```
vto.GlobalLayout += (sender, args) =>
    {
        // do stuff here
    };
```

You can get an instance of the ViewTreeObserver like this:

```
var contentView = activity.Window.DecorView.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content);
contentView.ViewTreeObserver.GlobalLayout += ViewTreeObserverOnGlobalLayout;
```

Comment: This works, however, I would like the event-handler to be executed only once. I have tried to create a method handler and in the method call a -= on the event. This doesn't seem to stop the handler from firing.

Comment: Can you explain what it is vto?

Comment: @Merian View tree observer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an information from Android Developers website :

> addOnGlobalLayoutListener(ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener
>   listener)
>
> Register a callback to be invoked when the global layout state or the visibility of views within the view tree changes

Here is the link you can take a look : [addOnGlobalLayoutListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html). and here [onGlobalLayoutListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener.html)